# Drupal 8 first MVC

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm trying to reach my first controller and view on a custom module with drupal 8. I'm new and this is my first custom module.

my_module.info.yaml located in /modules/custom/my_module

```
name: My Own Custom Module 
description: A silly example module
type: module
core: 8.x
```

With this, I've been able to go to my extension to activate the module.

So, the module is installed.

Now, I want to try to hit my first twig template

In order to do so

my_module.routings.yaml located in /modules/custom/my_module

```
my_module.article_list:
  path: 'my_module/articles'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ArticleController::page'
    _title: "Title routing"
  requirements:
    _permissions: 'access content'
```

My controller located in /modules/custom/my_module/src/Controller

```
<?php 
    namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

    class ArticleController{

        public function page(){

            $items = array(
                array('name' => 'Article one'),
                array('name' => 'Article 2')
                array('name' => 'Article 3')
            );

            return array('#theme' => 'article_list',
            '#items' => $items,
            '#title' => 'Liste d\'article');
        }
    }

?>
```

article-list.html.twig located in /modules/custom/my_module/src/templates

```
<h4>{{ title }}</h4>

<ul>
{% for article in items %}
    <li>{{article.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

my_module.module located in /modules/custom/my_module

```
<?php

function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
return array('article_list' => array('variables' => array('items' => array(), 'title' => '')));
}

?>
```

But then, when I try to reach my template I hit a page not found

```
http://localhost:9000/drupal-8.7.8/index.php/my_module/articles
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Generally if you add a new route the cache needs to be cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `my_module.routings.yaml`

but `my_module.routing.yml`

Also I think that path parameter must start with slash sign:

```
path: '/my_module/articles'
```

Comment: Damn you right, I also had an other error (I missed a coma in the controller). Looks like this is working now (well I have an access denied trying to access the page even with the admin account, so I guess I missed something, but at least the routing seems to be working ! Thanks.